# Displaying the calenday day

Tags: ruby, datetime, rspec

I have this (working) code:

```
class CalendarDay

  attr_accessor :from_month, :to_month, :year

  def self.line_of_day_numbers(month,year,start,offset)
    @line=''
    @offset=offset
    finish = (start+6)-@offset
    self.first_line_padding(start)
    start-= @offset
    self.day_numbers(month,year,start,finish)
  end 

  private

  def self.first_line_padding(start)
    if start < 7 
      @line=' ' * (@offset * 3)
      @offset=0
    end 
  end 
  ...
```

But the methods are tangled and there's a mix of instance and local variables.

Tests include:

```
it "shows the day numbers" do
  expect(CalendarDay.line_of_day_numbers(2,2000,1,2)).to eq '       1  2  3  4  5'
end
it "shows the day numbers" do
  expect(CalendarDay.line_of_day_numbers(10,2000,1,0)).to eq ' 1  2  3  4  5  6  7'
end
it "shows the day numbers" do
  expect(CalendarDay.line_of_day_numbers(1,2000,8,6)).to eq ' 2  3  4  5  6  7  8'
end
```

Comment: If the behavior in the `first_line_padding` can change, why not offer to yield a block?

Comment: can you show `CalendarDay.day_numbers`?

Comment: It's hard to make concrete suggestions without seeing how the rest of the class works. But generally I would suggest making your code more functional, less stateful, and reducing side effects. Practically this means not using class or instance variables unless there is some other purpose for them which cannot be achieved by simply passing the required values as arguments. For instance, could you either include the contents of `self.first_line_padding` in `self.line_of_day_numbers` or pass it offset and line as arguments? (and have it return the new value for offset)

Comment: Nat is right. Imperative programming, at least in this kind of algorithms, is a complete mess. Use a functional approach (no updates, explicit pass of arguments/return values).

Comment: + 1 for nat's functional approach. Mandatory question when it comes to time algorithms : is there a reason why you don't use built-in features provided by `Time` and `Date` core classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to create some helper functions as class methods.  If you do that, you probably want to use class variables (e.g. @@a) rather than instance variables.  I would like to suggest what I think may be a better way.

First, convert the instance variables you created with `attr_accessor` to class instance variables (not to be confused with class variables).  You can do that like this:

```
class CalendarDay
  class << self
    attr_accessor :from_month, :to_month, :year

    def line_of_day_numbers(month,year,start,offset)
      ...
      @sugar = 7
      x = 5
      @year = ..... 
      ...
    end
  end 
end
```

Now you can use `CalendarDay.from_month`. `CalendarDay.year = 2007`, and so on.  Here `class << self` is opening `CalendarDay`'s singleton class or metaclass.  (To be more precise, it sets `self` to that metaclass.)  You could add other class instance variables (`@sugar`), as well as local variables (`x`).  You can also add class instance methods, as I have done above.  You would invoke this method with:

```
CalendarDay.line_of_day_numbers(month,year,start,offset)
```

Notice that `self.` is not used in defining class instance methods.  That's because `self` is the class's metaclass when they are created.

Note that these are class instance variables and class instance methods, not class variables or instance variables or class methods or instance methods.  They are only available to the class object, `CalendarDays`.  If you were to create an instance of the class, `cal_day = CalendarDay.new`, you'd find `cal_day` would have no access to any of these class instance variables or class instance methods.

One of the nice things about doing it this way is that you can write your code between `class << self` and `end` in the same way you'd write code for a class instance.  All instance variables, local variables and instance methods are available to the class only.

For the record, there are a few (equivalent) alternatives to the `class << self/end` construct.  One is:

```
module CalendarDayModule
  attr_accessor :from_month, :to_month, :year

  def line_of_day_numbers(month,year,start,offset)
      ...
  end
end

class CalendarDay
  extend CalendarDayModule
end
```

I discussed that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151339/setting-a-class-instance-variable-of-an-extended-class/19151939#19151939).

Beyond this, I can make no suggestions for improving your code without seeing more of it, `day_numbers()` in particular.  BTW, within your `line_of_day_numbers()` class method, neither  `first_line_padding()` nor `day_numbers()` need be preceded by `self.`.